# Can I enable/disable a layout xml file the way I do with components in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to enable of disable a resource layout xml file dynamically the way I can do with components using [`PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int%29)

Can this be done?

Comment: an xml layout file? why?

Comment: you can do with layout inflater see this,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: @pskink it's for an A/B testing thing. Anyway, I ended up using two `ViewStub`s for the task. inflating the one associated with the active test. thanks.